# How to find out sk_buff structure size?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

Can anybody please help me regarding following issue:

I plan adding new protocol to existing Linux kernel. My doubt is how to find out sk_buff structure size before allocating memory using skb_alloc() call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as skb_alloc. I assume you actually mean to call alloc_skb or dev_alloc_skb. The size argument given to alloc_skb is the *buffer* size you want to allocate along with it. You don't need to calculate the size of the sk_buff structure, alloc_skb already knows that. In other words, if you plan on receiving a max ethernet frame (1518 bytes), you probably want something like this:

```
skb = alloc_skb(1536, GFP_KERNEL);
```

That allocates an sk_buff structure and an associated buffer of 1536 bytes. The actual buffer area is at "skb->data".

Comment: Thanks for comment gil Hamilton   My doubt is how header size for mac(ieee 802.11p)

Comment: Perhaps this QA is similar / helps?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169961/how-exactly-is-the-amount-of-space-allocated-to-a-to-be-transmitted-packet-skb-d

Comment: Thanks for all posting comments

Answer (score 0):

```
sizeof(struct sk_buff)
```

or if you're using pointer to sk_buff

```
sizeof(struct sk_buff)
```

Comment: Are these suppose to be the same?